# Special char in config.ini secret file - jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Secrets are uploaded in config.ini file with user/password & password conatins special char like %,# etc but when tried to add password without special char all works fine. With special char in password it throws 404 Forbidden error & tried escaping with single quotes & back slash but didnt worked.

```
[jenkins]

user=sysadmin    

password=password#72f

query_plugins_info=False

url=https://xxxxxx/ 

[job_builder]

ignore_cache=True

allow_empty_variables=True
```

Any clue will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about where are these exactly uploaded to and when? you are using job-builder and it fails to provide an incorrect password? or is this another kind of operation?

Comment: In Jenkins trying to upload secret file with above configuration & password conatins special char which is breaking & when i give other username/password without special char its working fine.